# Struct parameters in attributes

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have got the following sample code:

```
public struct TestData
{
    public readonly string Element;
    public readonly bool MandatoryInd;

    public TestData( string element, bool mandatoryInd )
    {
        Element = element;
        MandatoryInd = mandatoryInd;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false )]
public class Test : Attribute
{
    public TestData[] Values { get; set; }

    public Test( params TestData[] values )
    {
        this.Values = values;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
[Test( "3477", true, "3286", true, "3286", false )]
public class TestClass
{

}
```

Basically, I'd like a pair of parameters (string, bool) to be captured in the `TestData()` struct, but I am not sure if it's possible to do this.  I have tried the following, but I get a compile error "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type".

```
[Test( new TestData("3477", true), new TestData("3286", true), new TestData("3286", false) )]
public class TestClass
{

}
```

If this isn't possible then I will have to consider using multiple attributes, which I am doing successfully at the moment but I want a cleaner and more terser method.

Comment: @svick I get the "'EDI.Attributes.TestData' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'" error when I tried that.

Comment: I meant actually using the attribute multiple times by changing the constructor of `Test` to `public Test(string element, bool mandatoryInd)`, very similarly to what Marc proposes, just with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @svick I am currently doing this, but I wanted to see if there was any way of using a single attribute to do this.  Apparently, Selman22 has come up with a way of doing it, although it's not ideal but it's a good alternative that might work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you change the signature of your constructor and use a linq trick:

```
public Test(params object[] values)
{
     this.Values = values
            .Select((x, idx) => new {x, idx})
            .GroupBy(g => g.idx/2)
            .Select(g => new TestData(g.First().x.ToString(), (bool) g.Last().x))
            .ToArray();

}
```

But indeed it is not type-safe.

Note: You may want to use `Batch` method from `MoreLINQ` then your code will look better.

Comment: erm, no, it isn't; please show how you would use `[Test(...)]` in this scenario, in a way that compiles without saying "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry I don't get it.I have tried the same code in the question `[Test( "3477", true, "3286", true, "3286", false )]` and it worked.

Comment: @Selman22 ah, right; doesn't provide quite the IDE support that I think the OP is looking for, but technically it should work, yes; agreed. In particular, it isn't a "struct parameter in attributes" (title)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that isn't possible. Either use a `string` and parse it; or use multiple attribute declarations, i.e.

```
[Test]
[TestData("3477", true)]
[TestData("3286", true)]
[TestData("3286", false)]
public class TestClass {...}
```

Comment: This is what I am already doing, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do it using a single attribute.

Comment: @MikeClarke only if you use the "parse from a string" approach. With structured / compiler-checked data: no. There is a fundamental restriction in play here: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"